# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. while i use @method('PUT')

Tags: php, laravel

I've used the `@method('PUT')` in my blade, but it still says the `PUT` Method is not supported, does someone know what's wrong?

[image: controller]

My routes are:
[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvj7P.png)

This is my workshops controller edit parameter and storage.

```
public function edit(Workshops $workshops)
    {
        $result = compact('workshops');
        Json::dump($result);
        return view('admin.workshops.edit', $result);
    }
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Workshops  $workshops
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, Workshops $workshops)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required|unique:workshops' . $workshops->id,
        'datum' => 'required'. $workshops->id,
        'plaatsen' => 'required' . $workshops->id,
        'price' => 'required'
    ]);
    $workshops->name = $request->name;
    $workshops->datum = $request->datum;
    $workshops->plaatsen = $request->plaatsen;
    $workshops->price = $request->price;
    $workshops->save();
    session()->flash('success', 'The workshop has been updated');
    return redirect('admin/workshops');
}
```

Comment: Share your route please

Comment: everything looks ok. just make sure `$workshops` variable holds any value. it seems the variable is empty. and don't add your code as image. you can get a down vote for this.

Comment: Oh okay, didn't know that, i'm sorry. and yeah it's what i've learned at school but for some reason he doesn't accept the PUT method..

Comment: from where you are sending $workshops variable??

Comment: From my workshopcontroller, everything works until i try to add the put method.

Comment: can you inspect the form and find what's the generated url in the form's action??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also take a note of [why you should not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5698098). Always include textual content as `formatted` text in your question.

Comment: The generated url in the form's action is: <form action="/admin/workshops/" method="post' novalidate="true">

Comment: as i guess. the variable is empty and thus the id parameter is absent in the url. share your code from where you are sending to the edit page with the workshop variable.

Comment: added the controller parameters.

Comment: if you do `dd($workshops)`, do you get the expected values??

Comment: No, so i will look into that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: some how your route model binding is not working..look into that..

Answer (score 2):

Look in your routes file, you need Route::put() for the route you are trying to use. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
Route::post('/admin/workshops/{id}',  'ControllerNameController@methodName');
```

Comment: You mean Route::put()??

Comment: Not `COntrollerNameController` its `ControllerNameController`

Comment: It's my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your route with PUT as shown below

Route::put('/admin/workshops/{id}',  'ControllerName@methodName');

[Official Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#basic-routing)

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.in/laravel-tutorial/routing/)